# Does minimize requests fields saves more quota?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Since YouTube Data API comes with quota limitation, so we could trace our quota based on sent requests with given quota in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost).

But the documentation only comes down to "part" level instead of "fields" level, so for example...

```py
YouTube_Service_Public.search().list(
    part="snippet",
    channelId=channel_id,
    maxResults=50,
    order="date",
    type="video",
    fields="items(etag,id/videoId,snippet(publishedAt,thumbnails/default,title))"
).execute()
```

```py
YouTube_Service_Public.search().list(
    part="snippet",
    channelId=channel_id,
    maxResults=50,
    order="date",
    type="video"
).execute()
```

Does the first request cost less quota than the latter?

or do they cost equally 100 quotas since they all request "snippet" part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quota cost would be the same. The [fields parameter](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#fields) is just to reduce bandwidth usage.